# Connection error

Tags: pi-3

I have got connection timed out error while logging into the putty to connect to my raspberry pi-3 model B board.As per the documentation I have created an empty ssh text document but even then its showing the connection timed out error.Where did I go wrong?how can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you ping the Pi? "Connection timed out" suggests it's not able to connect to the device at all.  Could be general network issues.

Comment: How is the Pi accessing the network?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did a headless setup on my mac (should work on other conputers also)

1. Downloaded etcher and latest raspbian desktop image

2.inserted sd card, burned zip file with etcher to it.

3. etcher automatically ejects the sd card, reinsert it and make a text document named ssh (make sure it doesnt have an extension!)
4. copy the sh file to sd card and eject the sd card.
5. insert sd card micro usb and ethernet cable from pi to your router.
6. power up RPi, wait 2 mins than goto your routers ip address and type in your crednentials.
7. fibd device connected and find your raspberry pi ip address
8. open terminal and type ssh pi@(ip address of rpi)
9. enter raspberry as the password
10. change your settings with sudo raspi-config and reboot.
11. if you want to vnc to it enable vnc and connect.

Hope this helps!